# Conditional Formating with real date and time

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I want either to use Conditional Formatting or VBA code to solve this problem, it doesn't matter which.

I want to color `A1` conditionally. I have a process that ends at a specific date and time stored in `B1`. My process start date and time is stored in `B2`. I have coded a real-time clock in `C1`.

Let's say my process will end 2013-09-29 17:05:16 (stored in `B1`). I want to compare this value to the real-time clock in `C1`, that ticks every second.

I've four different conditions to satisfy for `A1`:

1. If `C1` is before `B1` then **Green** until `C1` reaches the final 3% of the Start-Stop interval.
2. Otherwise, if `C1` is before `B1` then **Yellow**.
   So it's basically an interval between 0.97 and 1.00 where 0.97 is 3%
   before the process ends and 1.00 is at process end.
3. If `C1` has passed `B1` by up to 3% of the Start-Stop interval, then **Orange**.
4. Otherwise, if `C1` is later than `B1` then **Red**.

I don't know if you guys need the coding for the real time and date (`C1`) but anyway:

```
Global clockOn As Boolean
Sub runClock()
    Range("C1").Value = Now()
    If clockOn = True Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "runClock"
    End If
End Sub
Sub startClock()
    clockOn = True
    runClock
End Sub
Sub stopClock()
    clockOn = False
End Sub
```

Comment: see [this](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/highlight-cells-based-on-a-condition/) for highlighting cells based on condition

Comment: @pnuts What I mean is 3% before C1 reach the process end time I want the cell at A1 to turn Yellow. C1 will ofcourse just tick since it updates all the time, so when C1 approaches "Process end date and end time" that is stored in B1, I want A1 to notice this (turn Yellow) when it is only 3% left before C1 actually reaches B1. Does this clarify more, or dit I just confuse you more?

Comment: @pnuts so dumb of me!!! You're absolutley correct, 97% would not work, it's obviously 3 years ago *gah*! Hmm.. then I've to consider another way to solve this problem. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @pnuts my *Start process Time* is stored in B2 - How could this help me? Little confused at the moment

Comment: @pnuts that's true! Thanks mate! I'll look into this and try to figure this out :). Your help is much appriciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNTESTED but I think it is something of this kind you need!:

[image: SO19024932 example]

where the formula in A1 is `=(NOW()-B2)/(B1-B2)`

Comment: Yeah I've noticed this now :). Ive the following now:
**Green A1 < 0.97**, 
**Yellow A1 < 1.00**, 
**Orange A1 <= 1.03**, 
**Red A1 > 1.03**, 

This is what I was lookng for, it seems to work when I test different start and end times. :)